# Rules: How to modify an existing condition programmatically

Tags: 7, rules

I've been able to add a condition to an existing rule, but I can't find any documentation on how to modify an existing condition on a rule. The following code works for adding but I need to modify the one that already exists. Any ideas?:

```
$hk_delivery_rule = rules_config_load('commerce_shipping_service_hong_kong_delivery');

$hk_delivery_settings = array(
    'first_price:select' => 'commerce-order:commerce-order-total',
    'operator' => '<',
    'second_price' => array(
      'amount' => $hk_threshold,
      'currency_code' => 'HKD'
    )

  );

$hk_delivery_rule->condition(rules_condition('commerce_price_compare_price', $hk_delivery_settings));
$hk_delivery_rule->save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So turned out it was quite easy:

```
  $hk_delivery_rule = rules_config_load('commerce_shipping_service_hong_kong_delivery');

  foreach ($hk_delivery_rule->conditions() as $condition) {

    if (isset($condition->settings['second_price'])) {

      $condition->settings['second_price']['amount'] = $hk_threshold;

    }

  }

  $hk_delivery_rule->save();
```